# Using the Lastpass extension on my app

Tags: ios, ios-app-extension, lastpass

I am trying to use the Lastpass extension on my iOS app, but I can't find any documentation about it... Even though lots of apps appear to support it, like Evernote and IF.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: It was a long time ago, and the passwords are encrypted on the client-side so if you have a long, strong password you are fine even if they are hacked again. There's a reason it's widely used... And a risk you have even if you use a local password manager (your computer can also be compromised)

Comment: Sure but it shows the competency of the company. RE my computer: physical access is necessary, not just a web request. From a greater perspective my computer is not as valuable as the LastPass database, multiply by the number of users.

Comment: Still, I need to sync the passwords between two computers and my mobile devices, and there's no safe way to do it. Anyway... I still want the question answered :P

Comment: Who's to say that Dropbox won't get hacked, and my 1password database stolen?

Comment: Well, if your 1Password database is stolen it is encrypted with your password derived key. LastPass claimed to be secure, they were hacked because they had poor security (poor security == no security), so they are security Bozos or at least were but I do not trust a Leopard to change it's spots.

Comment: If you read the news you posted, all that hackers possibly got was a database where passwords were also derived from your master key.

Comment: OK, trust a Bozo outfit that can't protext their database.